# Showing a compact form of a summation.

Tags: summation

How can I show that:

$$P^k \left(1 + \frac {2}{p} + \frac {3}{p^2} + \frac {4}{p^3} + ..... + \frac{k}{p^{k-1}} + \frac{k+1}{p^k}\right) = \sum_{i = 0}^{k} (k + 1 -i) p^i$$

Could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: try looking at it from the end to the beggining

Comment: What is $P$ supposed to be? maybe you mean $p$?

Comment: Induction should work.

Comment: @mathreadler: you should enter an answer showing that the claim holds iff $P=p$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : I am not master of all different kinds of $P$s. Someone else probably knows these $P$s better.

Comment: @mathreadler: $\text{Mathreadler}\notin\mathbb P$ ?

Comment: I might be a little bit both here and there, but it does not automatically make me a good choice for hopping out unexpectedly playing balalaika solos all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a change of summation index:
$$p^k\sum_{l=0}^k\frac{l+1}{p^l}= \sum_{l=0}^k(l+1)p^{k-l} \stackrel{i=k-l}{=}\sum_{i=k}^0(k-i+1)p^{i} = \sum_{i=0}^k(k-i+1)p^{i}$$

Comment: Wow you magically knew that $P$ was supposed to be $p$? Some mind reading skills there.

Comment: Yes, According to my magic $P = p$. :-)

Comment: Ok if you say so, master wizard of P.